# How to center the map according to specific coordinates

Tags: javascript, npm, openlayers, npm-install, openlayers-3

I am learning OpenLayers with javascript. I am following this tutorial

```
http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch01-getting-started-with-openlayers/example-01.html
```

the code works fine, but when i add the following line:

```
var birmingham = ol.proj.transform([-1.81185, 52.44314], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

and type

```
npm start or 
npm run start
```

nothing is to be displayed. when I remove the aforementioned line of code the map appears normally on the localhost.
I want the center of the map to be set to specific coordinates

please let me knoe what is wrong with the line of code mentioned above and how to fix it.
**code**:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import * as olTransform from 'ol/transform';

var source = new OSM()

var layers = [new TileLayer({
  source: source
})];

ol.projection.transform
//var birmingham = ol.proj.transform([-1.81185, 52.44314], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');// this line results in not to show the map
var view = new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 40,
  zoomFactor: 4
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: layers,
  view: view
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mixing module and full build syntaxes.

If the view projection is EPSG:4326 you do not need to transform, simply use the lon/lat value directly

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

var source = new OSM()

var layers = [new TileLayer({
  source: source
})];

var view = new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [-1.81185, 52.44314],
  zoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 40,
  zoomFactor: 4
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: layers,
  view: view
});
```

For other projections use

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';

var source = new OSM()

var layers = [new TileLayer({
  source: source
})];

var view = new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  center: fromLonLat([-1.81185, 52.44314], 'EPSG:3857'),
  zoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 40,
  zoomFactor: 4
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: layers,
  view: view
});
```

EPSG:3857 is the default for both `View` and `fromLonLat` and can be omitted.  `fromLonLat` is equivalent to

```
import {transform} from 'ol/proj';
transform([-1.81185, 52.44314], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```